# Exception sending three arrays with unnest(array[someArray]) in JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I can't send 3 arrays into an SQL statement, it throws an exception

```
select t.ttt, t.created_date, concat_ws('-',lp.mmm, lp.ccc, lp.eee ) from tasks t
join positions p on t.id = p.task_id
left join lte_position lp on p.id = lp.id
where t.ttt in (:identities) and (lp.mmm, lp.ccc, lp.eee) in
((select mmm,ccc,eee from ((select unnest(array[:mmm]) as mmm, unnest(array[:ccc]) as ccc, unnest(array[:eee]) as eee)) as temp))
order by t.ttt DESC
```

I want to send 3 arrays in `mmm`, `ccc`, `eee`. When I try that on the Postgres console it works fine, but when I try it in Java code, in throws an exception

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot cast type record to integer
Position: 474
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote it, PostgreSQL thinks that your whole parameter string is a single integer.

Rather than

```
unnest(array[:mmm])
```

use

```
unnest(CAST(:mmm AS integer[])
```

But then the parameter has to look like

```
{1,23,456}
```

including the braces. That is the string representation of an array in PostgreSQL.

**Additional observation:** Why do you use `:mmm`? a JDBC parameter has to be written as `?`.

Comment: {1,23,456} how to send this parameter with jdbctemplate?

Comment: Don't know, never heard of jdbctemplate. I thought the question was about JDBC.

Comment: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate for jaca Spring jdbc